# PHP, SNMP, and MIBs - Working in CLI

Tags: php, snmp, cisco, net-snmp, mib

**EDIT**

I feel pretty stupid about this. I just now noticed that on the CLI it returned the oid.1. PHP was just erroring out due to me not having the .1 at the end of the oid.

---

---

Here's what I have. I'm trying to poll a Cisco device to gather information regarding temperature, CPU usage, interface usage, etc via SNMP.

OS: CentOS 6.5 64bit
PHP: 5.4.28
NET-SNMP Support: Enabled
NET-SNMP Version: 5.5
PHP SNMP Version: 0.1

I'm able to perform the following and get the expected results.

```
snmpwalk 10.0.0.1 -c communityname -v 2c .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.109.1.1.1.1.5 2>/dev/null
```

This will return with

```
CISCO-PROCESS-MIB::cpmCPUTOtal5min.1 = Guage32: 1
```

However, if I try to run the following via PHP I don't get the same result.

```
$cpu = snmp2_get("10.0.0.1", "communityname", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.109.1.1.1.1.5");
```

Instead, that outputs this.

```
snmp2_get(): Error in packet at 'SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.109.1.1.1.1.5': No Such Instance currently exists at this OID
```

I don't know what I'm missing and to be honest I'm probably searching for the wrong thing to get me going in the direction I need. I don't understand why PHP keeps trying to use the SNMPv2-SMI mib vs the CISCO-PROCESS-MIB.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Post the resolution you found as an answer and then accept it.

Comment: I wasn't able to at the time due to the reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel pretty stupid about this. I just now noticed that on the CLI it returned the oid.1. PHP was just erroring out due to me not having the .1 at the end of the oid.